# (C) delete elements of an integer array under the for loop only if they satisfy the condition

Tags: c, arrays, loops, element

and/or make a new array with the remaining elements which did not satisfy the loop condition

so I have two arrays and I compare each element to each other, with the corresponding subscript so I can check for equality.

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if ( arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[i] ) {
       arrayOne[i] = -1 /UPDATE#1 I assinged the values to -1 since I really don't care what happens tp the "taken" ones, what I want is the statistics of how many became a couple, thus the couple++ counter
       couple++;  //frequency of same value for each respective subscript         
   }
}
```

I will be doing something else for the remaining elements (variable name will be *int single[ ]*)

1. I will delete if it is the same with the element that I just deleted (think of this as the other party unlucky enough not to match with the exact position in arrayTwo of its same value)
2. I will also delete duplicated remaining elements
3. I will just check if the remaining elements in arrayOne are present in arrayTwo with no regards to respective subscript

**Sample:**

```
 arrayTwo[] = {5,6,7,8};
 arrayOne[] = {5,5,8,5,4,4,4}; //comparing arrayOne to arrayTwo
```

**output:**

```
 couple = 1; //(since only element[0] of the two arrays are the same --> 5 == 5
 atlast = 1; //no regards to position or subscript as long as present in arrayTwo
```

**then:**

I should remove that `arrayOne[0]` which is 5, so my `arrayOne`'s (or I'll make new array).
remaining elements are 5, 8, 5, 4, 4, 4.

Then hey, 5 has been deleted (taken), so I don't need 5s anymore. So my remaining elements are 8, 4, 4, 4

By now, I only have 8,4,4,4. But 4 are duplicating, I only need one 4. So I delete duplicationg 4s.

At last, after deleting the taken ones I only have 8 and 4 elements in `arrayOne`. I will check for their partner in `arrayTwo`. (same value, no regards to subscript or position) meaning, I don't care about the position anymore, as long as I have of the same value in `arrayTwo`, that's what counts)

Only 8 has a partner in `arrayTwo`. I'll make it as `atlast++`, thus `atlast = 1`.

**what i don't have a clue how to do:**

1. delete the "taken" elements(couple) in arrayOne //no need, found another way
2. delete the remaining elements in arrayOne that are of the same value with the just deleted "taken" (couple) element/s //my arrayTwo contains unique, non-repeating random numbers, so assigning -1 to the taken ones make it easier to not care about the remaining duplicate in arrayOne (meaning while arrayTwo is unique each, arrayOne is not)

**Problem solved.**

for the atlast counter I subtracted it from the taken number. (I made it absolute value)
//unexpected solution, than you folks for giving me insights :)

**Insight**

My only required output was the frequency of couple and atlast. I was bombarded with the many rules with what I have to do and achieve. But perseverance really pays. Whew.

**One last run sample**

arrayTwo = {5,6,7,8,9} //unique random numbers, non-repeating
   arrayOne = {

Comment: In your example, why do you completely erase 5 (because it's duplicated), but when it comes to 4 you eliminate all but one of them?

Comment: Do you have a count of the number of valid elements in the array?  By delete, do you wish to deallocate the space as well?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Gonca because 5 has found a "couple" in arrayTwo (the first loop cares for the couple counter to check same value, same position. i.e., arrayTwo[0] = 5 and arrayOne[0] = 5, thus they match. It's like fated love. lol. Then the remaining 5s have no chance for love anymore since 5 has been taken. 4 remains since even though it has no fated love (exact value 4 at same position = impossible), it will have to wait for, say, necessity love (it doesn't matter if they did not meet at the exact same position, say position[3], as long as they match)

Comment: @cup i will initialize them randomly, 0 - 9 only, 6 elements per array. I just exceeded my arrayOne here to point out my goal. By deleting, I don't care about the remaining elements' positions anymore ( I know they will change in subscript or position in the array since the "taken" ones have been deleted in the array

Answer (score 1):

To delete an element from an array, you have to move all the elements after the index to be deleted down one, then decrement the length of the array.

Alternatives include:

1. Using a special "empty" value to indicate that this index has been deleted (your loop has to skip it and you may have to do math on your indices, but it's O(1) delete instead of O(n))
2. Using a linked list instead.

Comment: *then decrement the length of the array* Technically, you can't do that in C, at least not with explicit language support. Did you mean using a special pointer / index that denotes the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, I meant decrement the variable that you're using to keep track of the length of the array. If the array goes through any function formal parameters, `sizeof` stops being useful, so keeping a length variable around is handy anyway. Obviously the memory won't be freed, but that's why I mentioned linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

An other workaround could be to create an "arrayOneBis" and copy values from "arrayOne" skipping the elements you want to delete ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arrayTwo[] = {5,6,7,8};
    int arrayOne[] = {5,5,8,5,4,4,4};
    int size1 = 7, size2 = 4;
    //i will initialize them randomly, 0 - 9 only
    int counting[10] = {0};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size1;++i)
        ++counting[arrayOne[i]];//counting

    for(i=0;i<size2;++i)
        counting[arrayTwo[i]]=0;//delete
    size1 = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;++i){
        if(counting[i]){
            arrayOne[size1++] = i;
        }
    }
    printf("result arrayOne = { ");
    for(i=0;i<size1;++i)
        printf("%d ", arrayOne[i]);//{ 4 }
    printf("}\n");
    return 0;
}
```